# how to integrate convolution $\int f*g$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on this question:
$f$,$g$ are blocked, continuous functions and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|dx<\infty,\int_{-\infty}^\infty|g(x)|dx<\infty$.
show that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f*g)(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx$$

looking for some clues to put me on the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$(f*g)(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)g(t-u)du$$, so $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f*g)(t) dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)g(t-u)dudt$$, then we can change the order of integration by Fubini's theorem when you are manipulating the variables.